# New Composites not showing in Dialog

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am trying to add new composite to my dialog. I am creating a simple button and I want to place it in the dialog.  I first created a method to create the Button area.  This method is calling a method to create the simple button. The new button is not showing up in the dialog.

Here is the complete code

```
public class AplotBaseDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {

   private TCSession session= null;
   public AplotBaseDialog(Shell parentShell, TCSession theSession) {
       super(parentShell);
       session = theSession;
   }

   @Override
   protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
   Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
   GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
   layout.numColumns = 1;
   composite.setLayout(layout);

   // The text fields will grow with the size of the dialog
   GridData gridData = new GridData();
   gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
   gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.BEGINNING;
   Label label1 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
   label1.setText("First Name");
   label1.setLayoutData(gridData);

   gridData = new GridData();
   gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
   gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.CENTER;
   Label label2 = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
   label2.setText("Last Name");
   label2.setLayoutData(gridData);

   gridData = new GridData();
   gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
   gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.END;
   Button button1 = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
   button1.setText("Button 5");
   button1.setLayoutData(gridData);

   return composite;
}

protected void createButtonArea(Composite parent){
  GridData gridData = new GridData();
  gridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
  parent.setLayoutData(gridData);
  createOkButton(parent);

 }
 protected Button createOkButton(Composite parent) {
  // increment the number of columns in the button bar
  ((GridLayout) parent.getLayout()).numColumns++;
  Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
  button.setText("Test Button");
  setButtonLayoutData(button);
  return button;
 }
}
```

Why is Test Button not showing in up in the dialog?

Is something like this even possible in SWT/Jface?
[image: Desired dialog layout]

Can someone just show me the layout of the methods to do something like the dialog?

Comment: You never call `createButtonArea(Composite parent)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would be cleaner that instead of the `createButtonArea()` method you have created to actually override the `createButtonsForButtonBar` method. It would be more SWT friendly.

```
/**
 * Create contents of the button bar.
 * @param parent
 */
@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, "Test Button",
            true);
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID,
            IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, if he is really trying to create the "default" dialog buttons. But I'm not able to tell from his question. Might also be some random buttons...

Comment: I am just trying to learn how to add different components to my dialog.  I am having a hard time understanding how to add buttons, labels, table to a dialog using SWT.  I would not think you would have to add all the components in the createDialogArea method.  What if I wanted 2 buttons side by side at the top of the dialog, then have a table in the middle on the 2nd row, then have buttons side by  side on the bottom (3rd row) on the dialog.

Comment: @jkteater Then you should really read the Eclipse tutorial on [layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html). There is a plethora of examples...

Comment: Another thought would be to try to add a toolbar or find a replacement for TitleAreaDialog that supports toolbars. SWT is a lot different than Swing and has a lot less resources to learn from. I would suggest you grab an Eclipse RCP book or an SWT one.

Comment: @Dan There really is a lot to read about SWT: [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Catalog0280__SWT.htm), [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/javaswt/), [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SWT/article.html), [SWT Webpage](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/).

Comment: The biggest reason to call createButton() for your button bar is that it gets the order right.  If you are on Windows (and older GNOME), the platform look & feel is that your Cancel (or No) button is the furthest right, the OK (or Yes) button to its immediate left.  On Mac OS and recent GNOME, this is flipped (the OK button is furthest right.)  createButton() with the correct button IDs (as @Dan points out above) will always get this right.